# Sybase sp_who truncates hostname

Tags: sql, admin, sybase

I am connecting to sql databse using Rapid SQL or isql provided by sybase server. When I issue

```
sp_who username
```

command I should get list of connected users. I do but hostname column is truncated so for example when host address is host0001 it get truncated to host0 this is a problem because there are many hosts which names start with same prefix e.g. host001, host002.... Because of that I do not know which processes are blocking my database and I can not log to the machine and kill those processes. I do not have privileges to kill them from database isql console. I have to log to machine and kill process there (because I have privileges to stop those processes). The question is why sp_who truncates this column and how to prevent it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sp_who` pulls and joins information from several tables to give it's report.  It's not intended to produce output that can be used for input on something else.  If you need information from sp_who, it's better to just run your own query against `sysprocesses`.
Unfortunately, in this case, doing your own query won't help, as the hostname is not changed by `sp_who`.  In Sybase the hostname is set by the application that is connecting, not the server (try `select hostname from master..sysprocesses` and you'll see).

One solution would be to add a `set clientname` or `set clienthostname` command as part of your connection string from these other clients.  I believe this can be done via ODBC.  Othewise you can use the `sysprocesses.ipaddr` column to differentiate between hosts:

```
select fid, spid, status, suser_name(suid), clienthostname, ipaddr
from master..sysprocesses
where suid = suser_id('username')
order by ipaddr, spid
```

Comment: Thanks. That is very exhaustive answer. Are you Sybase developer?

Comment: Not a developer, but I have been a Sybase consultant.

Comment: It's pitty but it turn out that Sybase 12.5 do not have sysprocesses table or at least my user can issue sp_who but not select * from sysprocesses. Error message says that is sysprocesses not found.

Comment: Try specifying master..sysdatabases

Comment: Ok, now I get it you mean select * from master..sysprocesses and that works. Thanks again for making my life easier.

Comment: Yes, that is correct..I've updated the code in the answer as well.