# Sybase get the program name that is running SQL

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

Requirement is to get program name that runs sql command and store it in a column in audit table. Have added login id using 'suser_name()' function. But need to program that is running the command.

I'm using Sybase Adaptive Server 12.5.

Thanks!

This is what I was looking for:

`select
    suser_name (suid) as 'suser_name',
    ipaddr,
    program_name,
    loggedindatetime
from master..sysprocesses
where spid = @@spid`

Comment: Sybase was a company, not a database.  Which Sybase product are you referring to?

Comment: If you know the username, then you should be able to use the code provided here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315665/sybase-sp-who-truncates-hostname/19321664#19321664

Comment: Your welcome.  Make sure you upvote the link if you found it helpful.